# How to I choose a random number between 20000 and 64000

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to use autossh to specify a random port each time, i.e.

```
autossh -M $RANDOM root@X.X.X.X
```

But I want the random range to be between 20K and 64K.

I couldn't find the answer easily. Any bash script wizards out there who can help?

Comment: Choose a number between 0 and (64000 - 20000) then add 20000.

Comment: Thanks folks - I love the shuf command

Comment: Why random? You should pick an unused port and use it. I think the default is fine for most. You certainly don't want to accidentally collide with something else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
shuf -i 20000-64000 -n 1
```

This should work like a charm

Comment: I would have done `seq 20000 64000 | sort -R | head -n 1`. However, if causes SIGPIPE to sort. Your answer is much cleaner...

Answer (score 3):

Use the modulo operator:

```
let "port = $RANDOM % (64000 - 20000) + 20000"
autossh -M $port root@X.X.X.X
```

Comment: perfect answer. Can you just 60k to 64k? just sticking to question :)

Comment: @Antarus Fixed. Note that [Amir's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17487557/35070) is even shorter and easier to write.

Comment: Yes. But `shuf` is not found in older bash.

Comment: `shuf` isn't found in any version of `bash`. It's a separate program.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -e 'print rand(64000-20000) + 20000'
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be handled with a simple shell expression, no need for external commands with modern shells:

```
port=$(($RANDOM % (64000 - 20000) + 20000))
```

Or straight away:

```
autossh -m $(($RANDOM % (64000 - 20000) + 20000)) root@x.x.x.x
```